# "Doubling" array in prepared statement to fill duplicate placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

God this is so annoying. I have a messagesystem with inbox, outbox, and a conversation view. The conversation view shows both sent and received messages with a specific user, and since I only use one table for the messages (sender_status/receiver_status to control which of the users involved in the message have deleted it, read it etc.)

I have checkboxes next to my list, one for each message, it works fine in my queries both for inbox and outbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="message_delete[]" value="<?= $message['mid']; ?>"/>
```

I need to apply the messageupdate to the correct status when I try to delete in the conversation-view:
Normal query, i.e. inbox, works fine:

```
$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($mid_array) - 1) . "?";
$st = $db->prepare("UPDATE messages SET sender_status = 'DELETED' WHERE mid IN ($questionmarks)");
            $st->execute($mid_array);
```

Conversation-query, does not work:

```
$st = $db->prepare("UPDATE messages SET (receiver_status = 'DELETED' WHERE mid IN        ($questionmarks) AND to_user = '{$user_id}'), (sender_status = 'DELETED' WHERE mid IN ($questionmarks) AND from_user = '{$user_id}')");
            $st->execute( WHAT TO PUT HERE );
```

I have tried array($mid_array, $mid_array) in the execute which I thought would work. Also several other somewhat stupid solutions that I can´t get to work. I´m probably missing some easy function here but none of the ones i´ve tried have worked, hence my question. Need Help!! thanks in advance.

Comment: your second query is totally invalid. you cannot have multiple `where` clauses like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like

```
UPDATE messages
SET
    receiver_status = 'DELETED',
    sender_status = 'DELETED'
WHERE mid IN ($questionmarks) AND ('$user_id' IN (to_user, from_user))
```

to get around the multiple `where` issue in your original query.

---

```
SET
   receiver_status = IF(to_user   = '$user_id', 'DELETED', receiver_status),
   sender_status   = IF(from_user = '$user_id', 'DELETED', sender_status)
WHERE mid IN ($questionmarks)
```

instead, then?

Comment: The problem here is that I then will set the message to deleted for the user that is not currently trying to delete the message, no?

Comment: Trying it right now, I will vote it when I can confirm it works :P, and if so - thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks man it worked, upped you and checked it now. small note to someone who wants to copy it though, there is an iffy little comma ',' missing from after the parenthesis in between the two SET options, you should probably update that. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Whoa.
You just can't do that, with prepared statements or without.
It's SQL syntax, not PDO.

So, just run 2 separate queries with 2 separate sets of data.

By the way, for some reason you're not using placeholders in your query - so, you're in danger.